# [JAVA]How to create a Ranking System then saving it to a .txt file?

Tags: java, file, memory, ranking

So, I have a "Memory Game", you can input your name, choose the difficulty(4x4 or a 6x6 game) and then start the game.
When you click Start, a new Panel will pop up and the game will start.

The buttons will be randomized and for each mistake you make, you lose 2 points and for every right combination, you gain 10 points.
At the end or if you click on the Exit button, a message will pop up stating the Player's Name, how many tries he did(clicked 2 different buttons) and how many Points he has. Then the game ends and it doesn't save the Player's Score.

Now, my problem is, I don't know how to implement a Ranking System in my code. It would be something basic, like, a comparison between all the Scores and rearrange them to the one with the most points comes first and so on.

So from what I researched, I would need a Save method that whenever someone finishes a game it would save their scores in a .txt file and an Array method that would arrange the scores form Best to Worst.

Here's the whole code;

http://pastebin.com/6Wtiju7z

```
private void mostrarResumoJogo() { 
    resumoJogo = "Jogador: " + objJogadorJogada.getNome() + " " +
            "Pontos: " + objJogadorJogada.getPontos() + " " +
            "Quantidade de tentativas: " + qtdeTentativas;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "" + resumoJogo, "Resumo do Jogo",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE ); 

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("Ranking.txt") );
        writer.write(resumoJogo);
    }
    catch ( IOException e) { }
    finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close( );
        }
        catch ( IOException e) { }
    }

    setVisible( false );
}
```

The problem is that the file is always overwritten with a new .txt
I already tried to create a type File attribute so that he doesn't always create another .txt but with no success.

It's the last thing that I need to do on this code, but I can't seem to figure it out, please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the file is always overwritten with a new .txt

Problem is here

```
writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "Ranking.txt"));
```

Each time you invoke `new FileWriter( "Ranking.txt")` it creates new empty file. If you want to add more data to already existing file you need to open it in append mode via

```
writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "Ranking.txt", true));
//                                           add this part -^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what are you looking for

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Just specify APPEND parameter as true and your changes won't be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

To make it not overwrite, but append instead pass append=true when calling the FileWriter constructor.

Instead of doing that though I would recommend just reading and writing the whole file every time. This is because the scores have to be sorted and rewritten to the file.

I would recommend using JAXB to create an XML file. Here is a tutorial for using JAXB to do this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/